# Suggestions for constructing block matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two nxn square matrices A & B. I would like to construct a block matrix whose (i,j)th block is a 2x2 diagonal matrix whose (1,1)th entry is the (i,j)th entry of A, and whose (2,2)th entry is the (i,j)th entry of B.

I am very new to MATLAB and have never coded before and cannot figure out how to do it. Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you are new to Matlab, why don't you start with one of the many tutorials ? You'll get the language basics and will surely very rapidly know how to solve your problem. Plus we prefer to answer to people that already have tried something.

Comment: are there any tutorials you can suggest?

Comment: @neil - Try mine.  I used this when I used to teach back in the day: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7ozdbphl727s6c/ELE532_MATLABTutorial_Full.ppt?dl=1 - When you're finished with that, try my more advanced tutorial: http://www.slideshare.net/rayryeng1/advanced-matlab-tutorial-for-engineers-scientists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More information on the problem would be helpful, are you confident that a block matrix you described will give you what you need.

```
A = rand(3);
B = rand(3);

out = cell(3);
for k = 1:numel(out)
    out{k}(1,1) = A(k);
    out{k}(2,2) = B(k);
end

out = cell2mat(out);
```

Comment: Hey Brian, I am positive, mathematically speaking what I described above is what I am looking for. Ideally I would have a function whose inputs are matrices A & B and this block matrix would be the output.

Comment: Awesome - then the above should work fine... If you don't want to use "for loops" especially for large matrices (so long as your RAM is large enough)

out(1:2:3*2,1:2:3*2) = A;
out(2:2:3*2,2:2:3*2) = B;

Comment: Thanks man. I wasn't aware of the cell function or the use of "squigly" brackets before.

Comment: I've been trying to do it with two for loops, for i & j but haven't been able to get it to work. This is a lot easier